# Deploy Fabric8 Spring Boot Container

Tags: redhat, fabric8

I am trying out a `Fabric8 Spring Boot` quickstart, following the steps documented [here](https://fabric8.io/gitbook/springBootContainer.html) I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.fabric8:fabric8-maven-plugin:1.2.0.Beta4:deploy (default-cli) on project my-spring-boot-rest-module: Execution default-cli of goal io.fabric8:fabric8-maven-plugin:1.2.0.Beta4:deploy failed: Plugin io.fabric8:fabric8-maven-plugin:1.2.0.Beta4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.karaf.deployer:org.apache.karaf.deployer.blueprint:jar:2.4.0.redhat-620004, org.apache.karaf.admin:org.apache.karaf.admin.management:jar:2.4.0.redhat-620004, org.apache.karaf.features:org.apache.karaf.features.core:jar:2.4.0.redhat-620004, org.apache.karaf:apache-karaf:zip:2.4.0.redhat-620004: Failure to find org.apache.karaf.deployer:org.apache.karaf.deployer.blueprint:jar:2.4.0.redhat-620004 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

I am running with `Maven 3.3.9` and `Java 1.8.0_91` on `Ubuntu 14.04`

Does this guide just not work, or am I missing something from my configuration?

Points to consider:

1. My `~/.m2/settings.xml` is untouched
2. The project archetype that I download as part of the first step is untouched (aside from the `mvn install`
3. I am running `Fabric8` inside `JBoss Fuse 6.2.0.redhat-133` on my local machine
4. I have already tried running `mvn -U fabric8:deploy -DskipTests` to update snapshots (to no effect)
5. [This totally useless issue](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1547723) is the only Redhat acknowledgement of this problem - and changing my `Maven` to the ancient `3.2.3` version (necessitating a change to `Java 6` runtime) is not going to fix the problem going forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fabric8 v1 is part of JBoss Fuse, and you can find documentation how to use it as part of the JBoss Fuse product documentation: http://developers.redhat.com/products/fuse/overview/

The Maven Archetype goal to use is different version number than what you type, you must use the version number of the JBoss Fuse product version you use.

In the upstream community fabric8 is now on version 2 which is a different architecture based on Kubernetes and Docker. Unfortunately you found an old documentation of the fabric8 v1 in that gitbook. The fabric8 version 2 documentation is what you can find from the website at the documentation page: https://fabric8.io/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does version 2 of fabric8 come packaged within OpenShift?

Comment: Parts of fabric8 v2 are productized in the Fuse Integration Service product (FIS) - https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/using_images/xpaas_images/fuse.html

And JBoss Fuse will in the future also migrate to fabric8 v2 (likely in version 7.0 onwards). But its company decision so take my word as not official